# Sort components of a vector numerically which contain letter numbers and letters

Tags: java, sorting, vector

Is there any way to sort a vector numerically?(i wanna sort the number before the first **; (semicolon)**

I need let's say this (it's a vector with 4 String/components)

```
[
 7394;dasd;dasda;dasda;5;3  

 2222;dasdasd;das;true;7;4;dsda;60  

 6660;dsada;dasasd;true;6;3 

 2345;dasdsagfd;das;true;7;4;gfgfdgd;60
]
```

to become this

```
[
 2222;dasdasd;das;true;7;4;dsda;60

 2345;dasdsagfd;das;true;7;4;gfgfdgd;60  

 6660;dsada;dasasd;true;6;3  

 7394;dasd;dasda;dasda;5;3
]
```

or this `[3123;dasdas;31;31        1115;das;31;312        4412;sdf;31;42]`

to `[1115;das;31;312        3123;dasdas;31;31        4412;sdf;31;42]`
(im sorting 3123, 1115, and 4412 numerically but i still keep the things after)

I've thought of converting each components to a string and then doing something like:

```
int count;
for(int i=0;i<string_component1.length();i++){
    if(Character.isDigit(string_component1.charAt(i)){
    count = i;
    break;
   }
}
```

and then with substring i would take the part i want, put it on a string, convert it to an int, then i would take the first one(lowest), use vector *contains* to find in which components its in and take this components to put it on a new vector at the first position. and so on with the others components

but i think its too much code for nothing and it wouldn't work since the vector size can be 3 or 50.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but I do not see any sorting order in your expected result? What do you mean by "sorting numerically"?

Comment: you could create a `Comparator` to implement your sorting and then call Collections#sort on your vector: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29]

Comment: "I've thought of converting each components to a string". Wait! What are they before the conversion? What kind of vector is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there any way to sort a vector numerically?(i want to sort the number before the first ; (semicolon) )**

The general pattern to sort a `java.util.Vector` is to implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass it to the [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method. All the logic for sorting order can then be put into the [`compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method of the `Comparator`. In your case, it could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] input = {"7394;dasd;dasda;dasda;5;3", "2222;dasdasd;das;true;7;4;dsda;60",
                    "6660;dsada;dasasd;true;6;3", "2345;dasdsagfd;das;true;7;4;gfgfdgd;60"};
  Vector<String> vec = new Vector<>();
  vec.addAll(Arrays.asList(input));
  System.out.println("Input : " + vec);

  Collections.sort(vec, new Comparator<String>() {

     @Override
     public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int i1 = Integer.valueOf(o1.split(";")[0]);
        int i2 = Integer.valueOf(o2.split(";")[0]);

        return i1 - i2;
     }
  } );

  System.out.println("Result: " + vec);      
}
```

Output:

```
Input : [7394;dasd;dasda;dasda;5;3, 2222;dasdasd;das;true;7;4;dsda;60, 6660;dsada;dasasd;true;6;3, 2345;dasdsagfd;das;true;7;4;gfgfdgd;60]
Result: [2222;dasdasd;das;true;7;4;dsda;60, 2345;dasdsagfd;das;true;7;4;gfgfdgd;60, 6660;dsada;dasasd;true;6;3, 7394;dasd;dasda;dasda;5;3]
```

Comment: he wants to sort Strings that begin with numeric characters

Comment: Thank you very much , it's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the elegant way of doing it using Collections.sort() with a Comparator:

```
Vector<String> vector;

Collections.sort(vector, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return getInt(s1) - getInt(s2);
  }
  int getInt(String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("(\\d+).*", "$1"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah my favourite Class: `Strung`. :)

Comment: I've spent too long in New Zealand lately :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your sorting order, but you can sort a collection using a [Collection.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29),

You can use `Collection.sort()` to sort your list and implement a custom Comparator to order elements the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you strings have a fix pattern you could do something like:

```
int indexOfSemi = string_component.indexOf(";")
```

With this you have the first semicolon.
And then with:

```
String myNumber = string_component.substring(0,indexOfSemi-1)
```

And now you have your number which you must convert to int.
Do this in a **Comparator** class and you have your comparing mechanism.